# Triple integral differences from double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am starting to learn about triple integrals, and I don't see the difference from double integrals. With a double integral we can find volume, density, center of mass, and area under a curve in R3 space. With a triple integral we can also find the same things. Also, it seems like both double and triple integrals operate in R3 space? The only difference I see is that we have a z-axis in triple integrals, but that doesn't seem like a big deal since we can use a double integral to find the space under a curve in R3 without the z-axis. What is the difference between these integrals?

Comment: What kind of functions are you integrating? How complicated are these integrals you've been exposed to?

Comment: @user170231 I wouldn't say they are too difficult. We learned about mass, moment of inertia, and center of mass yesterday and just opened the chapter on triple integrals. We also learned cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: I suspect you haven't had enough exposure to appreciate the need and usefulness for adding a third integral. How might you set up a double integral to, say, find the volume between the planes $x+y+z=1$ and $x-y+z=1$ over the square $[0,1]^2$? (Not to suggest it's impossible, but it is much easier to set up the 3x integral that reduces to a 2x integral)

Comment: Why do you think useful mathematics ends at 3 dimensions? You can only find *average* density from mass and volume, and you can only find mass and center of mass from density by a double integration in limited circumstances. I'm sure any calculation you've done has just assumed density is constant, but that is not generally the case. You yourself have a wide range of different densities in various parts of your body. You can only model the complexities of the real world with integrations over (at a minimum) 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in the fact that the triple integral and the double integral essentially has the same properties (only, of the ones you mentioned, I will keep the idea of volume)  and that's a "good" because from a triple integral we can go to a double integral, the problem is when we try to do the converse. Because, they are differents, of course. I will not go into technical details about their differences because it is best to directly review a textbook and see its construction. However, I will write two differences that I find convenient at this moment given the context of your post. However, the important difference here is how the two integrals are constructed.

- If $f(x,y)\geqslant 0$, then $\iint_{D} f(x,y)\, dA$ is the volume under the surface $z=f(x,y)$ and over the region $D$. However,  if $f(x,y,z)\geqslant 0$, then $\iiint_{E}f(z,y,z)\, dV$ will be the hyper-volume of an object living in ${\bf R}^{4}$.
- Using double integrals our domain of integration $D$ is in ${\bf R}^{2 }$ and the graph of $z=f(x,y)$ is in ${\bf R}^{3}$. However, with triple integrals our domain of integration $E$ is in ${\bf R}^{3}$ and the graph of $w=f(x,y,z)$ is in ${\bf R}^{4}$ (that we can't even graph anymore)

In terms of the application that I am discussing here, point two is key. That is why in double integrals we are concerned with finding the region of integration in the plane, whereas in triple integrals we are concerned with what the region of integration looks like in space.  It is also there where the application of volume gains more force, because using triple integrals we can find the volume between two surfaces and this is always easier with triple integrals than with double integrals.

With triple integral we have in one-case-projection
$$V(E)=\iiint_{E}\, dV=\iint_{D}\left[\int_{u_{1}(x,y)}^{u_{2}(x,y)} \right]\, dA=\iint_{D}(u_{2}(x,y)-u_{1}(x,y))\, dA,$$
and here we are calculating the volume between the surface $u_1$ and $u_2$. But with double integrals we do not have so much strength, observe
$$V=\iint_{D}(\underbrace{u(x,y)}_{>0}-0)\, dA,$$
and it is the volume between under the surface $z=u(x,y)\geqslant 0$ and the region $D$ in the plane. So triple integrals are significantly useful, of course and in a sense "stronger than" double integrals.